# Blazor Server Add Claims after authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side, claims-based-identity, claims

Hi I want user to select branch to enter after login and user may have different role for each branch. Then this info will be added to user claims. Below is how I implemented  IClaimsTransformation TransformAsync method.

```
public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            // Clone current identity
            var clone = principal.Clone();
            var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

            // Support AD and local accounts
            var nameId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier ||
                                                              c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (nameId == null)
            {
                return principal;
            }

            // Get userInfo from database
            UserBranchRoleModel userInfo = await Task.Run(() => _userService.GetCurrentBranchRole(nameId.Value));
            if (userInfo?.User == null)
            {
                return principal;
            }

            List<Claim> claims = new()
            {
                new Claim(newIdentity.NameClaimType, userInfo.User.UserID),
                new Claim("BranchID", userInfo.Branch.BranchID.ToString()),
                new Claim("BranchName", userInfo.Branch.BranchName),
                new Claim(newIdentity.RoleClaimType, userInfo.Role.RoleID)
            };
            newIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
            return clone;
        }
```

The problem is claims don't get updated if I do not refresh the page. Is there any way refresh claims without refreshing page altogether ?

Here is How I display claims in Index page

```
@foreach (var c in @user.Claims)
{
    <div>@c.Type:  @c.Value</div>
}
```

And this is how I Update DB

```
    async Task changeBranch(string UserID)
    {

        DialogOptions options = new DialogOptions() { CloseButton = false };

        DialogParameters parameters = new DialogParameters();
        parameters.Add("UserID", UserID);

        var dialog = DialogService.Show<ChooseBranch>("Select A Branch", parameters, options);
        var result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Cancelled)
        {
            UserBranchRoleModel BranchRole = (UserBranchRoleModel)result.Data;
            _user.SetCurrentBranchRole(BranchRole);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `The problem is claims don't get updated if I do not refresh the page.` are you sure? A page won't re-render itself if some data it knows nothing about changes. When you use data binding the page will detect changes and update itself. Otherwise you need to tell it there was a change with `StateHasChanged`. How do the claims affect the page? Are you displaying them somewhere? Or modifying the UI based on the claims?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried `StateHasChanged` But it doesn't work.. Yes I display the claims on my component.

Comment: Post the code. People can't guess what's going on with code they don't see

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated question with code..  All the codes are working without any issue.. Only thing is that claims dont change if page is not refreshed.